# Swap without worrying about the data type

Tags: c, pointers

Is that implementation valid and safe to swap two array or variable without worrying about their data type? Or should I use a function pointer?.

This type of code is focusing about using a good implementation of void pointers to swap without worring about the data type.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap(void *, void *, int);

int main(void) {

  char a[] = "home";
  char b[] = "door";

  printf("%s %s\n", a, b);
  swap(&a, &b, sizeof(a));
  printf("%s %s \n", a, b);

  return 0;
}

void swap( void *a, void *b, int siz){
  char buff[siz]; // I voluntarily omitted dynamic allocation.
  memcpy(buff,a,siz);
  memcpy(a,b,siz);
  memcpy(b,buff,siz);
}
```

Comment: `char buff[siz];` is not valid (standard) C++, so start by deciding on one language

Comment: Only because this question is tagged [C++], I'll just mention `std::swap`...

Comment: It's not safe at all. If `sizeof(a) != sizeof(b)` you have a problem.

Comment: Why can't we just swap the addresses of the variables? I mean doesn't something like this work: `char *c = a, *d = b; a = d; b = c;`

Comment: This could be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). For which reason do you need the swap the contents of two arrays? The answer probably depends on that reason.

Answer (score 4):

In C, this approach is usually okay (and it's used by standard functions such as `qsort()`).  The contra-indications that indicate you can't use this are when there are any pointers to your objects or their members.  Also, take care in multi-threaded code.

Note that in C++, we have `std::swap()` which will respect user-defined copy/move constructors; copying a C++ object by simply copying its memory is not (in general) valid.

Answer (score 1):

This `swap()` function is as good/bad as the `memcpy()` it uses.

- If the data structures are just some data structures (of `int`, `float`, etc.), it works like a charm.
- If you pass two pointers to different structures, all hell will break loose. Offending code:

  ```
  Foo* myFoo = ...;
  Bar* myBar = ...;
  swap(myFoo, myBar, sizeof(*myFoo));
  ```

  Note that your compiler won't complain on this as both pointer types are implicitly convertible to the `void*`s that `swap()` expects. But the result of compilation will be bullshit.
- If the structure you copy contains a pointer into itself, that pointer will point into the other object after the `swap()`. The following `struct` would be an offender of this:

  ```
  typedef struct {
      char* data;
      size_t length, allocatedLength;
      char shortStringBuffer[32];
  } myString;
  ```

  The idea behind this is, that short strings will be stored in the `shortStringBuffer`, and `data` will point to the `shortStringBuffer`. Strings longer than 31 characters will be stored in dynamically allocated memory, and again be accessible via the `data` member. It is left as an exercise to the reader to figure out, what precisely happens when you try to copy this thing with a `memcpy()`.

What you must understand, is that `memcpy()` really only copies bytes, and some data is not invariant to where it is stored. So, each and every use of `memcpy()` must be accompanied with a proof that it does the correct thing in this particular case. Well, it *should*. I've never seen such a proof in a comment for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

You can just swap their addresses without further operation to swap two variables/arrays. I tried this and it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *a = "home";
    char *b = "root";
    char *c = a, *d = b;
    printf("%s %s\n", a, b);
    a = d;
    b = c;
    printf("%s %s \n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
home root
root home
```

https://ideone.com/MMCOpf

Comment: Right, it's never safe to use a swapped variable inside any code without also swapping their dependencies like already assigned pointers to the variable or any parts of it etc. But this way, you can be sure it's completely swapped in every aspect.

Comment: This works (and is usually best) when the subsequent code accesses the object through a pointer.  Sometimes, though, we need to move by copy.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to use generic pointers to swap, however you must make sure you get the sizes right, and that you don't overflow any array or object:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int swap(void *a, void *b,
    size_t a_size, size_t b_size);

int main(void) {

    char a[] = "home";
    char b[] = "door";

    printf("%s %s\n", a, b);

    int ret = swap(a, b, sizeof(a), sizeof(b));
    if(ret) {
        printf("%s %s \n", a, b);
    }
    return ret;
}

int swap(void *a, void *b,
    size_t a_size, size_t b_size)
{
    if (b_size != a_size ) {
        return 0;
    }
    void *tmp = malloc(a_size);
    if(!tmp) {
        return 0;
    }
    memcpy(tmp, a, a_size);
    memcpy(a, b, b_size);
    memcpy(b, tmp, a_size);
    free(tmp); // tmp no longer needed.
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by C, code for your reference.

Using **uint16_t** is neccessary to hold the carry bit when two large uint8_t variables plus.

```
int main(){
    uint8_t tmp[9] = {0x0};
    for (int i=9-1; i>=0 ; i--) *(tmp+i) = 0xff-i;
    uint16_t tmp2[9];
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++) tmp2[i] = tmp[i];
    byte_swap_uint8_data(tmp2, 9);
}

void byte_swap_uint8_data(uint16_t* data, int w) {
    if (w < 2) return;
    for (int i=0; i<w/2; i++) {
        data[i] += data[w-1-i];
        data[w-1-i] = data[i] - data[w-1-i];
        data[i] = data[i] - data[w-1-i];
     }
}
```

Comment: How is this related to the question? It does not swap 2 variables but reverses an array. And you seem to require `uint16_t` array to hold only `uint8_t` data for some reason. Just using a temp variable would be more efficient than adding and subtracting stuff like you do.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I shared my experience and code related to solve this issue, so sorry that it's not helpful to you.

Comment: Sorry to mention it, but the code does not solve this issue. It solves a completely different problem.